# Form fields edits by Javascript fail when user edits field

Tags: javascript, forms, drag-and-drop

This is the bare bones of some javascript I wrote without much experience. I think the error is probably something obvious that I just can't seem to find. The process is that a user can move elements into a design area; and then email the design specs with ID#s of the elements. The bug is that if a user decides to edit the form fields directly, the part of the script that automatically inserts the text stops working. Is it a "return;" action that is missing? Or a "focus()"? I've tried a few things with those 2 that haven't worked. I'll upload this little file here: http://professional.maigreysmind.com/afwebs-files/forum/test.html in case you don't want to mess with running it locally. And thank you so much in advance, if you can help me.

```
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        if (ev.target.id == "position1") {
            document.getElementById("form-block1").innerHTML = document.getElementById(data).id;
        }
        else if (ev.target.id == "position2") {
    document.getElementById("form-block2").innerHTML = document.getElementById(data).id;
        }
        else if (ev.target.id == "position3") {
            document.getElementById("form-block3").innerHTML = document.getElementById(data).id;
        }
        else {};
    }

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div style="position:relative; float:left; border:1px solid black; width:70px; height:70px;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div style="border:1px solid black; width:68px; height:68px;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="WJ1431" width="68" height="68">container</div></div>

        <div style="position:relative; float:left; border:1px solid black; width:70px; height:70px;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div style="border:1px solid black; width:68px; height:68px;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="WJ1426" width="68" height="68">container</div></div>

      <div style="position:relative; float:left; border:1px solid black; width:70px; height:70px;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div style="border:1px solid black; width:68px; height:68px;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="WJ1418" width="68" height="68">container</div></div>

    <div style="clear:left;">&nbsp;</div>



    <div style="width:70px; height:70px; border:1px solid black; float:left;" id="position1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <div style="width:70px; height:70px; border:1px solid black; float:left;" id="position2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <div style="width:70px; height:70px; border:1px solid black; float:left;" id="position3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>


    <div style="clear:left;">&nbsp;</div>

    <form id="form17" name="webapp-form" method="POST" action="">
     <div style="float:left;"> <table width="220" bgcolor="#f4f1e7" border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td><textarea id="form-block1" type="text" cols="7" rows="4" maxlength="24"></textarea></td>
          <td><textarea id="form-block2" type="text" cols="7" rows="4" maxlength="24"></textarea></td>
          <td><textarea id="form-block3" type="text" cols="7" rows="4" maxlength="24"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div></form>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've edited a `<textarea>`, its `innerHTML` is ignored. You need to set its `value`, like any other input field. So change to:

```
if (ev.target.id == "position1") {
    document.getElementById("form-block1").value = document.getElementById(data).id;
}
else if (ev.target.id == "position2") {
    document.getElementById("form-block2").value = document.getElementById(data).id;
}
else if (ev.target.id == "position3") {
    document.getElementById("form-block3").value = document.getElementById(data).id;
}
```

BTW, `document.getElementById(x).id` is the same as `x`.